# Is my solution correct or is it just a coincidence of the answer?

Tags: geometry

Circle $A$ has $1/3$ the radius of circle $B$, and circle $A$ rolls one trip around circle $B$. How many times will circle $A$ revolve in total? I got the correct answer, which is $4$, but is my solution correct, or is it just a coincidence of the answer? My solution to this problem:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 \pi \cdot\left(x+\frac{1}{3} x\right)}{\frac{1}{3} x \cdot 2 \pi}=4
\end{equation}

Comment: It's correct...

Comment: Can you explain how you came up with that equation? Without the explicit reasoning, it's hard to know how you thought of (say) $ x + 1/3 x$. Like you said, the numerical answer is correct, but the underlying reasoning might not be.

Comment: x+1/3x means: Circle A radius + Circle B radius, that makes a new circle and  circumference and then I divide it by the circle A circumference. Of course visual explanation might be better, but I hope it makes sense. So could you confirm or prove, that this solution is correct or incorrect?